# SVG text with ‘stroke-dashoffset’ CSS animation not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

The following animation works fine in Chrome and Opera, but it doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox. I can't figure out why.

Can someone please help me to fix the problem? What is wrong with my CSS?

```css
#text-logo {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  -moz-animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  -webkit-animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  background-clip: text;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="draw_text">
  <svg width="1092" height="220">
    <text x="150" y="200" fill="#fff" stroke="#333" id="text-logo" stroke-width="2" font-size="95">WHO I AM ?</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Units have to match in Firefox so if the base is a percentage unit then the animated value must be in percentages too.

There's no such thing as a -moz-animation or -moz-keyframes and any prefixed animations should be placed before the unprefixed version. I've fixed that too below.

```css
#text-logo {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  background-clip: text;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }
}

}
```

```html
<div class="draw_text">
  <svg width="1092" height="220">
    <text x="150" y="200" fill="#fff" stroke="#333" id="text-logo" stroke-width="2" font-size="95">WHO I AM ?</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think the `webkit` prefix is needed any more.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `stroke-dashoffset: 100%` looks like a neat thing, but 100% of what? The [canonical definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeDashoffsetProperty) is:

> If a percentage is used, the value represents a percentage of the current viewport …

> […](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units) the percentage is calculated as the specified percentage of `sqrt((actual-width)**2 + (actual-height)**2))/sqrt(2)`.

Firefox seems to not implement that. Setting `px` lengths makes it work:

```css
#text-logo {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1114px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1114px;
  -moz-animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  -webkit-animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  animation: draw 8s forwards ease-in;
  background-clip: text;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="draw_text">
  <svg width="1092" height="220">
    <text x="150" y="200" fill="#fff" stroke="#333" id="text-logo" stroke-width="2" font-size="95">WHO I AM ?</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Firefox certainly does implement the canonical definition of percentages.