# Show several sections (specified by percentages) of an SVG path

Tags: svg, path

I have several SVG path elements, which I want to be displayed only partially as several sections. For this, I have percentages for the parts of the paths that should be visible. E.g., the two pairs (0.3,0.5), (0.75,1.0) indicates that a path should be visible from 30% to 50% and from 75% to 100% of its length. How do I implement this in an SVG?

I have tried linearGradients, which do not work precisely for curved paths.
I also thought that this problem is trivial by using stroke-dasharray, but this does not work correctly with percentages (at least what I have tried).
Unfortunately, I also cannot invoke JavaScript in my environment, as the SVG attributes can only be directly accessed.

Does anyone have an idea or can enlighten me?

Comment: Try to add the [`pathLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) attribute to you path. With a pathLength of 100 you can apply a value like `stroke-dasharray=50 100` to render a stroke of 50% length. Check also svg pie or donutchart on SO which often use this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea with `stroke-dasharray`. Why percentages do not really work, see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987713/svg-text-with-stroke-dashoffset-css-animation-not-working-in-firefox/45988354#45988354). The solution consists of two steps:

1. For the path (or the grafic primitive), define an attribute (**not** a CSS property, and unitless) `pathLength="100"`. 100 is an arbitrary number here, but fits nicely with the use of percentages. The effect is that for all calculations that depend on a path length, the attribute value is used instead of the real length so that a dash length of 1 simply means 1/100 of the total path length.
2. Divide the total path length you defined in groups of dash lengths and gap lengths. Set the resulting list as the value of `stroke-dasharray`, and take care that the sum of all numbers in that list equals the defined `pathLength`. Note that the first number must be a dash. If you want to start with a gap, move the length of the gap to the end, and set `stroke-dashoffset` to the **negative** length of the initial gap.  (You could use `px` units here, but they are not needed.)

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 9;
}
#dash-first {
  stroke-dasharray: 30 20 25 25;
}
#gap-first {
  stroke-dasharray: 20 25 25 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 20">
  <path id="dash-first" d="M10,5 90,5" pathLength="100" />
  <path id="gap-first" d="M10,15 90,15" pathLength="100" />
</svg>
```

---

I recently used that idea to compute breaks in a long "wall", see this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ccprog/pen/rNPoNxP). In the Javascript section you will find a a method `Wall.sectorsToDashes()` that converts a list of Boolean values into a dasharray, where `true` means the stroke is shown as a dash, and `false` as a gap. The `pathLength` value is the length of the list, and each entry corresponds to a unit length of 1.

Comment: So easy once you know it!  Thank you very much, that helped me a lot.